# WSO2 APIM 3.1.0 integration with Azure AD

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to integrate **Azure AD** with **WSO2 APIM 3.1.0**.

I have configured the **IDP** as A**zure AD** and the **SPs** for dev portal. When a user is trying to login to the dev portal, the first step works fine and the sign in page is redirected to Azure. The first step of the **Oauth** flow also works fine in retrieving the authorization code. But the next step of the Oauth flow is failing when the **access token** is supposed to be retrieved from the auth code. When the **apim** tries to connect to the endpoint to obtain the access token, it fails probably since it is retrieving a localhost endpoint for that step.

I think it should be login.microsoftonline.com endpoint. Could you please help?

here are the logs after I added a couple of logs in the jag file -

```
TID: [-1234] [devportal] [2020-12-07 22:06:35,705] ERROR {JAGGERY.services.login.login_callback:jag} - tokenEndpoint: https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token
TID: [-1234] [devportal] [2020-12-07 22:06:35,708] ERROR {JAGGERY.services.login.login_callback:jag} - tokenRequestData: [object Object]
TID: [-1234] [devportal] [2020-12-07 22:06:35,709] ERROR {JAGGERY.services.login.login_callback:jag} - base64encoded: ------------------------------------------------------
TID: [-1234] [devportal] [2020-12-07 22:06:35,748] ERROR {JAGGERY.services.login.login_callback:jag} - Could not retrieve access token. Response: {"error_description":"Invalid authorization code received from token request","error":"invalid_grant"}
```

Comment: Looking at the error, it seems the returned authorization code is invalid. Have correctly configured the federated IdP in the Devportal service provider?

Comment: Yes, the authorization code returned by MS is valid and when I try to get access token from MS endpoint using that same code, it works fine and does return the access token. So WSO2 is not able to connect to the right endpoint to get the access token i.e. the 2nd part of the Authorization Code flow

Comment: @VithursaM could you please respond to this query?